# How to aggregate-initialize this struct?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

I'm having a struct that I would like to initialize like this:

```
checkPoints someCheckpoints = {
    {
        mPosition(10, 18),
        mPosition(15, 20),
    },
    {
        mPosition(45, 80),
        mPosition(95, 105),
    }
};
```

Basically a vector of position vectors initialization using aggregators.

This is working without problems:

```
std::vector<PosVec> someCheckpoints = {
    {
        mPosition(10, 18),
        mPosition(15, 20),
    },
    {
        mPosition(45, 80),
        mPosition(95, 105),
    }
};
```

However I need to use struct in order to add some additional functionality.

My code:

```
struct mPosition {
    mPosition(int32_t x, int32_t y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    int32_t x;
    int32_t y;
};

typedef std::vector<mPosition> PosVec;

struct checkPoints {
    explicit checkPoints(std::vector<PosVec>& checkPoints) {
        checkPointsVec = checkPoints;
    };

    const PosVec& getRandom() const {
        return checkPointsVec[getRandomInt(0, checkPointsVec.size())];
    }

    std::vector<PosVec> checkPointsVec;
};

checkPoints someCheckpoints = { // no matching constructor
    {
        mPosition(10, 18),
        mPosition(15, 20),
    },
    {
        mPosition(45, 80),
        mPosition(95, 105),
    }
};
```

This is producing `no matching constructor` error. I would like it to use a proper vector-like aggregation constructor. Should my struct extend vector class 
instead or would I be able to do this declaring my own constructor (which one)?

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector` is not represented by braces. When using in initialization, you're using `std::initializer_list`. And `const` is making a difference. So I would like to write

```
explicit checkPoints(const std::initializer_list<PosVec>& checkPoints)
                     ^~~~~      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In this way your constructor can catch literal constants.

Also, as [*Jarod42* noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361479/how-to-aggregate-initialize-this-struct#comment81676014_47361518), an `explicit` constructor cannot be called like `checkPoints a = {};`. You can only call it like

```
checkPoints a { /* stuff */ };
checkPoints a ( /* stuff */ };
```

Do note that you're using an rvalue initialization here, so it won't be catched by a non-const lvalue reference. It can only be catched by an rvalue reference or a const lvalue reference.

```
checkPoints someCheckpoints = {
    {
        mPosition(10, 18),
        mPosition(15, 20),
    },
    {
        mPosition(45, 80),
        mPosition(95, 105),
    }
}; // This is an rvalue!
```

Anyway, it's a good practice to declare parameters as const if you don't modify the reference in it.

Comment: With `explicit`, it would be `checkPoints someCheckpoints { .. }` (no `=`)

Comment: and with `vector` would need extra brace, `initializer_list` would avoid that.

Comment: Adding `const` doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. Regarding `explicit` I can either use `{ .. }` and `= { .. }`. I'm using it since single argument constructors should be marked like that to avoid unintentional implicit conversions.

Comment: @Kesse Try `std::initializer_list`

Comment: @iBug Looks like this one will work. Thanks. PS. Since now it's initializer list constructor no longer need for explicit declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor needs a `std::vector<PosVec>` as input parameter, like this:

```
     checkPoints someCheckpoints{ 
        std::vector<PosVec>{
        {
            mPosition{10, 18},
            mPosition{15, 20},
        },
        {
            mPosition{45, 80},
            mPosition{95, 105},
        }
        }
    };
```